# Testing dao layer with @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am writing unit testing using **@DataJpaTest**. Though it should do automatic rollback after every method, it is not doing that. Can you please help me with this.

This has 2 test cases written, ideally, test2 should return null, but it returns 1.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired TestEntityManager em;

    @Autowired EmployeeRepository rep;

//  @Autowired EmployeeService service;
    //Spring context loaded only once, reused by other methods
    @Test
    public void test1() {
//      System.out.println(service); No such bean found
        Employee e= new Employee();
        e.setName("Payal");
        em.persist(e);
        em.flush();
        Employee emp=rep.findByName("Payal");
        assertNotNull(emp);
        assertThat(emp.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Employee emp=rep.findByName("Payal");
        assertNull(emp);
    }
}
```

Complete code can be found at: 
https://github.com/payalbnsl/SpringUnitTestDemo/tree/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/dao

Comment: I've just executed the tests and they work fine. How do you run them?

Comment: All the test cases should be independent to each other! this is a bad technic! the success never should depend on the order of the execution of test cases . all the test cases should be success alone still on you mom's computer. it shouldn't depend on other test cases and the environment at all!

Comment: @TheBitman , This is exactly what issue I am facing. 2nd should pass but it fails if it executes Test1 first.

Comment: Sergi, for you, it might have executed Test2 first. Check the order in which it is running test cases.